# Send WiFi credentials wirelessly to a RPI

Tags: networking, wifi

I am trying to send WiFi credentials over the air to raspberry pi for it to auto write to /etc/suppliant.conf. I want the pi to serve a web page in a web server mode, display WiFi available networks. On receiving valid credentials, the pi will only connect as a client.

I found loads of materials online, but none really tells about this web server and switch in a single frame.

Comment: You need to add "What have you done" not just mention "loads of material". Please read the https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask